# Python-Convert docx to pdf using docx2pdf import convert , but throwing errors AttributeError: Word.Application.Documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, python-docx, file-conversion

i am trying to convert to .docx to pdf using convert method. Earlier it was working but now i see error in the output.Kindly suggest

```
#Converting docx to pdf format
from docx2pdf import convert

# Bulk Conversion
convert(r'C:\Users\ABC\',r'C:\Users\ABC\New\')
```

Output:AttributeError: Word.Application.Documents
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2lt3.png)

Comment: Hi, without changing path it worked. Looks like  garbage collection issue but not sure as sometimes its working and if executed multiple times its throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having a path issue, from the documentation I can see

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert("input.docx")
convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
convert("my_docx_folder/")
```

Can you try to maybe change the path?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).